# nested tile definition does not work

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles2

I am new to tiles and simply wish to make them work in the following scope
base.jsp

```
...<body id="pageBody">
<div id="container">
      <tiles:insertAttribute name="intro"/>
      <tiles:insertAttribute name="supportingText"/>
      <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu"/>
</div>
```

...

where intro.jsp is

```
    <div id="intro">
  <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
  <tiles:insertAttribute name="quickSummary" />
  <tiles:insertAttribute name="preamble" />
</div>
```

So in simple terms, I wish to have a tile definition named intro which is to be used inside a tile definition named base.jsp

in my tiles-defs.xml I have:

```
<tiles-definitions>

<definition name="base" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/base.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Template"/>
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/header.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/footer.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="intro" value="intro"/>
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/menu.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="resources" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/resources.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="supportingText" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/supportingText.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="intro" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/intro.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/header.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="quickSummary" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/quickSummary.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="preamble" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/preamble.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

So I was hopping this would work and the content of header.jsp, quickSummary.jsp, preamble.jsp would be available in the rendered page.

Instead I get as final result:

...`</head>
    <body id="pageBody">
    <div id="container">
            <div id="intro">
      <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
      <tiles:insertAttribute name="quickSummary" />
      <tiles:insertAttribute name="preamble" />
    </div>
            <div id="supportingText">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="content"/>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"/>
    </div>
              <div id="linkList">
        <div id="linkList2">...`

In my spring configuration I have:

```
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" p:definitions="/WEB-INF/tiles-defs/tiles-defs.xml" />
<bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver" p:basename="views" />
```

Any ideas if what I am trying to do is feasible (sounds really common scenario so I guess it is) and if yes what I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `cascade="true"` to `put-attributes` to cascade `header`, `quickSummary` and `preamble` to nested tiles.

See also [documentation about nesting definitions](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/nesting-extending.html).

Comment: perfect answer. straight forward up to the point and accompanied with the link i was looking for...
Thank you Slava